# Is there a way to create a always on top window using Xlib on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, xlib

I wrote a program which used the following code to open a window on windows which used gdi+ to draw to the window. What are the Xlib equivalent methods of gdi+:

```cpp
    WNDCLASS WindowClass = {}; // Initialize Windows class to 0

    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = MainWindowCallback; 
    WindowClass.hInstance = Instance;
//  WindowClass.hIcon
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = L"basicWindowClass";
    WindowClass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(AppBackroundR, AppBackroundG, AppBackroundB)); // Greyish

    CreateWindowExW(
                WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE |
                WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_PALETTEWINDOW,     // Top Most Window, No button on taskbar, No close Button
                WindowClass.lpszClassName,                  // Class Name
                L"Basic",                               // Window Name
                WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,     // Windows which is visible and does not have a close button and stuff
                50,                                         // X                                      //
                0,                                          // Y                                      // Top Right Corner
                300,                                        // Width                                  //
                175,                                        // Height                                 //
                0,
                0,
                Instance,
                0);
```

I wanted to port it to linux, however I got stuck on window creation. Is such window creation possible? If yes, please share an example. I tried gtk, glfw, and ended up with Xlib. Is my choice wrong?

Comment: What was the issue with all those things you already tried? It surely can't be a lack of example code. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You need to set the EWMH window state _Above_. You should include more context to the question so we understand your needs and be better able to answer a question with appropriate framework/library to use. Almost nobody uses Xlib directly these days.